Efficient Method for Solving KKT problems
In the attached inequality, constrained, optimisation, problem. Looking at the specific case where $\lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2 > 0$ that I am trying to solve, you can see that I have managed to find half of the critical points, however, the mark scheme identifies additional critical points from this case (-2,0) and (2,0) these can be seen fairly easily from inspection of the constraint. However, I am concerned that there should be a systematic way of finding them apart from just guessing values in the constraint, and I think I would have missed them.

Is my approach correct so far?
How would I have found these other critical points systematically?
Is there a better or faster way of solving this case for the 4 critical points?

Apologies for uploading hand written solutions, i have RSI from typing, and so excessive typing is problematic atm. Thanks for your understanding!

